# Blazor WASM components in Razorpages

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a existing application using Razorpages. I found possibilities to integrate server-rendered/server-prerendered Razor components, but I would like to use some client-side Razor components in my application.
Is this possible? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code than Blazor WASM index.html. That's it.

Comment: But how can I include components?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio